Change TOC color only
I am currently writing a report for my internship on LaTeX. I am using TeXstudio since my file was becoming too large for free Overleaf to compile. I have many referencing in it, and I would like to change their colour to blue. I used the command below (I specified everything since I was trying to fix this), and my in-text references are indeed appearing blue (like "Fig.x" when citing a figure or "[x]" when citing an article) but my issue is that my TOC also appears blue. I found out that it was the "linkcolor=" controlling that but setting it to black also set my figures/part referencing to black as well. Is there a way to have these references blue, while keeping my TOC black?
Thanks in advance.
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,pagecolor=black,menucolor=black]{hyperref}


You need to compile twice after adding like here
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
right after \begin{document}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,linkcolor=blue,pagecolor=black,menucolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
\tableofcontents
\section{1}

\section{2}
\end{document}


Ah thank you so much it worked!
